# ui-router $stateChangeState event cannot trigger

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i want to load an animate when routechange.
why nothing in console.

html

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<a ui-sref="home">home</a>
<a ui-sref="route">route</a>
<ui-view></ui-view>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.bootcss.com/angular-ui-router/1.0.0-rc.1/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
```

js

```
    var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router']);
    app.config(function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider
                .state('home',{
                    url:'/home',
                    template:'<div>home</div>'
                })
                .state('route',{
                    url:'/route',
                    template:'<div>route</div>'
                })
    })
    app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

    });

    app.run(function($rootScope,$state){
        // $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
            console.log(111);           //why cannot?
            // load.onLoading();        //loading animate..
        })
    });
</script>
</body>
```

i want to load an animate when routechange.
why nothing in console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From angular-ui-router docs:

> State Change Events
>
> NOTE: State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by
>   Transition Hooks as of version 1.0 (details)

And to migrate from legacy to the most recent angular-ui-router version:

```
// Legacy example
app.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
   // some code
  });
});

// Migrate to: UI-Router 1.0 Transition Hook
app.run(function($transitions) {
  $transitions.onStart({ }, function(trans) {
    // some code
  });
});
```

Source [here](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use [ng-animate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) module to animate page route. You can see the docs here. You can also check for this tutorial. [Tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/01/20/angular-nganimate-tutorial-with-ui-router)

Comment: Why is that better?

Comment: for animating things the angular way, better to use angular libraries. You can see the CSS tricks link here. https://css-tricks.com/animations-the-angular-way/